# How to get the div current text box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple div's with text box want to get the each div input box value and display it into that div itself

**HTML :**

```
 <div id="product_data" class="ui-sortable">
  <div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name"></strong> </h3>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
                <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute_2" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes" class="woocommerce_attribute wc-metabox ">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name"></strong> </h3>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
                <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute_3" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes" class="woocommerce_attribute wc-metabox ">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name"></strong> </h3>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
                <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the input field value "id = attribute_name" and display the value into the " " on blur function and this was dynamic text box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "input" ).blur(function() {
   var string = $(this).val();
   $(this).parent().append(string);
});
```

This will append the text on removing the cursor from the input . Style it as your requirement. Atleast it should give you an idea of what to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/L4UQJ/

Comment: But this value should display in above parent of the element ie..

<h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name"></strong> </h3>

Comment: Inside the  <strong class="attribute_name"></strong>  only :(

Comment: Add some HTML to the string . Make a div with relative positioning and background color white. Then you need a close button and you have to remove the previously created div when the close button is clicked.

Comment: You have duplicate id's which is not recommended. Fix them and post the code here. Then i may write some code for what you want . Also do not make the classes so redundant .

Comment: Because i'm cloning the main div '<div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute" style="display: block;">' ie..that's why it's getting duplicate id's

Answer (score 1):

Since those HTML elements are generated dynamically, use this below approach.

```
   $(document).on('blur', '#attribute_name', function () {
      console.log($(this).val());  //To get the value of the textbox
      $(this).val(' ');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
 $("input[type='text']").on('blur', function () {
          alert($(this).val());  
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Finally It's working :)**

```
$( "input" ).blur(function() {
            var string = $(this).val();
            $(this).closest('div').find('h3 > strong').html(string);

        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aarukarthiga/rJ844/)